# How to extract string between characters in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table with a column which includes a string with multiple topic names. I am looking to split out the first topic name (and if possible the second and third). The string can contain up to 8 topic names.

The format of the string is:

```
["T.Topic1", "T.Topic2", "T.Topic3", "S.Topic4", "S.Topic5"]
```

I have tried the following but wanted to know if there was a better way that would not involve the need to remove the left characters " and the right character " in a subsequent line or a possibility to extract more than the first topic.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(split(l.Intent, '[\\,]')[0], 2) AS TOPIC_1
FROM Table l
```

Results:

`"T.Topic1"`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are really close to the solution.
I suggest that you try and tackle it in 2 stages.

1. Remove the Array
2. Split the string.

- `regexp_extract(l.Intent,'^\\["(.*)"\\]' )` This will get the text inside the array.
- `split ( text , '", "' )` will split the string into the array you want.

putting it together:

```
with l as (select '["T.Topic1", "T.Topic2", "T.Topic3", "S.Topic4", "S.Topic5"]' as Intent)
select
   split ( 
     regexp_extract(l.Intent,'^\\["(.*)"\\]')
     , '", "' ) as array_of_topics 
from l as topics;
```

You can now access these rows `topics.array_of_topics[0]`,`topics.array_of_topics[1]`,`topics.array_of_topics[3]`

Comment: If you found my comment helpful please upvote. If you are comfortable marking it as the answer I'd appreciate you marking it so when you have time.